# Activity sometimes crash not everytime due to exception on void android.view.View.unFocus

Tags: android, exception, nullpointerexception

I am getting null pointer exception on void android.view.View.unFocus. I found three similar questions on stack overflow but all of them have issues like they didn't initialize any variable  or something like this. But in my case i am not providing any code here. I just want to know why this error occur. Its not appear every time but sometimes. In my case i am just getting images from camera or gallery and then post it to server along with some other info. I am not using methods like onStop , onResume. Just using onCreate. Here is the complete error.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.plan9.qurbaniapps.qurbani, PID: 10768
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.plan9.qurbaniapps.qurbani/com.plan9.qurbaniapps.qurbani.Activities.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.unFocus(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4035)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4084)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap24(Unknown Source:0)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1622)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.unFocus(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
       android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:5229)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewAt(ViewGroup.java:5192)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:17                                                                 
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3227)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStop(FragmentManager.java:3204)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchStop(FragmentController.java:236)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStop(FragmentActivity.java:597)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStop(AppCompatActivity.java:183)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1375)
       at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:7181)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4032)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4084) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap24(Unknown Source:0) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1622) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
03-04 22:40:34.796 10768-10768/com.plan9.qurbaniapps.qurbani E/CrashlyticsCore: Failed to execute task.
                                                                                java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.submitAndWait(CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker.java:41)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.handleUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:312)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$6.onUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:296)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:30)
       at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
       at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1063)
       at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:1955)
```

And this error stop crasheletics to report crash. So please tell me way this error occure. Is there something i have to do in onResume or in onPause,onStop ?
And i now what null pointer exception is so its not a duplicate question.

Some code here:

```
makepost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                p = new ProgressDialog(MakePostActivity.this);
                if(makepost.getText().equals("Edit")){
                    p.setMessage("Editing...");
                }else {
                    p.setMessage("Posting...");
                }
                p.show();
                if(toggleButton.isChecked()){
                    salevalue = "true";
                }
                else{
                    salevalue = "false";
                }

          //      if(imageView.getTag() != null && !description.getText().toString().equals(""))

                if(imageView.getTag() != null && !category.isEmpty())
                {
                    makepost.setEnabled(false);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Post will be uploaded in few seconds" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(datafile == null) {
                        credentialsProvider();
                        TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client, getApplicationContext());
                        String[] arr = imageView.getTag().toString().split("/");
                        File file1 = new File(imagePath);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "category: " + category, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        imageName = arr[arr.length - 1] + generateUniqueFileName();
                        TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(
                                "*******",     /* The bucket to upload to */
                                imageName,    /* The key for the uploaded object */
                                file1        /* The file where the data to upload exists */
                        );

                        transferObserverListener(observer);
                    }
                    else{
                        makepost.setEnabled(false);
                        sendEditRequest();
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    p.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Upload Any Image and Choose the category" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }
        });

private void sendrequest()
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("session"  , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        iddd = sharedPreferences.getString("id" , "");

        NetworkHelper.getServices().createPost(iddd,imageName,description.getText().toString(),category,"AUDIO" , salevalue).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, retrofit2.Response<String> response)
            {
                if(response.isSuccessful() && !response.body().toString().equals("-1"))
                {
                    makepost.setEnabled(true);
                    p.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Successfully Posted" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent it = new Intent(MakePostActivity.this , HomeActivity.class);
                    if(category.equals("Goat")) {
                        it.putExtra("VP", 2);
                    }
                    else if(category.equals("Cow")){
                        it.putExtra("VP" , 1);
                    }
                    else if(category.equals("Sheep")){
                        it.putExtra("VP" , 3);
                    }
                    startActivity(it);
                }
                else
                {
                    makepost.setEnabled(true);
                    p.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could'nt upload due to an error!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t)
            {
                makepost.setEnabled(true);
                p.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could'nt upload due to an error!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        trackScreen("Make Post Screen");
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                try {
                    datafile = null;
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, bytes);

                    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(MakePostActivity.this.getContentResolver(), bitmap, uri.getPath(), null);
                    file = Uri.parse(path);


                    imagePath = getRealPathFromURI(file);
                    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_gallery);
                    Picasso.with(MakePostActivity.this).load(path).fit().into(imageView);
                    imageView.setTag(imagePath);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (requestCode == 3 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                datafile = null;
                File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CameraDemo");
                file = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file1);
                bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, bytes);
                String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(MakePostActivity.this.getContentResolver(), bitmap, file.getPath(), null);
                file = Uri.parse(path);

                //path.get
                imageView.setTag(file.getPath());
                imagePath = getRealPathFromURI(file);
                Picasso.with(MakePostActivity.this).load(path).fit().into(imageView);


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: No @MeosCoder. I know what null pointer exception is. But my question is different. I am actually not getting why in this case null pointer exception occure

Comment: why you don't show code?

Comment: actually i am not sure where error occure. I have two activities. One is home activity and other one is Make Post activity. When i click on make post button then some times this happen. But in exception it shows that unable to stop Home activity. Both activities have a lot of code.

Comment: Should i post the whole code of both activities ?

Comment: You should more details to all can help

Comment: I have edited my code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `onActivityResult`. When you open the next activity, this activity is being destroyed. When you try to come back to this activity `imageView` is null and it crash when you try to execute this line `imageView.setTag(file.getPath());`
The easiest way to test this is going to your phone settings -> developer options -> don't keep activities

Comment: Thank you.. i will try this

Comment: so you recommend that i should initialize imageview in onResume() ?

Comment: You can do it in onResume or in onActivityResult